# A $\partial\bar\partial$ type problem in Kähler Geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

On any compact Kähler manifold $M^n$ one can ask: given a closed $p,q$ form $\alpha$ on $M$ does $\exists\beta\in\Omega^{p-1,q-1}(M;\mathbb{C})$ such that $\alpha=\partial\bar\partial\beta.$

I am interested in a similar question, given a form $\alpha\in\Omega^{n-q-1,n-p-1}(M;\mathbb{C}),$ when can we find a $\beta\in\Omega^{p,q}(M;\mathbb{C})$ such that $\alpha=*\partial\bar\partial\beta.$ What conditions one should impose on $\alpha$ to ensure a solution. Here $*$ is the complex-linear extension of the Hodge star operator on real forms.

In case, it's hard to deal with the general problem, my current problem deals with a Kähler 3-fold and I am trying to solve the equation $*\partial\bar\partial:\Omega^{1,1}\rightarrow \Omega^{1,1}; *\partial\bar\partial\beta=\alpha,$ for a given $\alpha$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to assume that $\alpha$ is co-closed, i.e. $*\alpha$ is closed?

Comment: Yeah, that certainly does it. The problem is it's not always easy to check any property of $*\alpha$, I was hoping if we can get something more. But I think that's the best we can do.

Comment: I think your first sentence should only be true locally, not globally.  I have not thought about this stuff for years, but I think even the volume form on the Riemann sphere does not have a global Kahler potential?

Comment: @StevenGubkin, Yeah.. you are correct. I missed this important point. The global problem is harder than I thought. I'll edit the question accordingly. Any idea about the special case in Kahler $3$-fold?

Comment: The $\partial \bar \partial$-lemma precisely says that $\alpha = \partial \bar \partial \beta$ has a solution if and only if $\alpha$ is exact. Moreover, it is enough to verify that $\alpha$ is closed and $\bar \partial$-exact (see https://math.unice.fr/~hoering/hodge/hodge.pdf, paragraph 4.D). Hence $\star \partial \bar \partial \beta = \alpha \Longleftrightarrow \partial \bar \partial \beta = \pm \star \alpha$ has a solution if and only if $\star \alpha$ is exact.